# How to have function affect all objects in a class and not just the last one created

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures, phaser-framework

I have an if statement that creates text objects by reading strings from array based on index position.

```
if (ifpn > 12){
     list = game.add.text(game.world.centerX+850, yfp, text, style);
      game.physics.arcade.enable(list);
      list.inputEnabled = true;
      list.input.enableDrag();
      list.events.onDragStart.add(startList, this); 
      list.events.onDragStop.add(stopList, this);
    }
```

in that statement I have a listener event that fires a custom function out side of its scope.

```
function startList(selected){ 
  var posx = game.input.mousePointer.x;
  var posy = game.input.mousePointer.y;

  if (canc > 0){
    console.log('too many');
  }
  else {
    if (list.position.y > posy){
      list.position.y = list.position.y-40; //doesn't work as expected
    }
    else{
      console.log('too tall');
    }

    game.world.remove(selected);
  }
};
```

What this function does is when a user starts dragging the *list* object it gets the y position of the mouse and subtracts 40px form the height of any other *list* objects below the mouse at the point of the click. 
But because *list* is defined as a global variable `list = null;` and then given a value out side the scope the statement only affects the last created *list* object due to closure.

How do I make the height properties of all the *list* objects change and not just the last one created?

please correct any errors you see in my codes or explanation of the issue.

Thanks

Comment: your variable `list` is not a `array`, it's the reference of your last added `text` object. You overwrite it each time you create a new `text`.

Comment: Add all text object into an Array and then you can apply changes one by one.  Or add all text object into a Phaser.Group object and then apply change to the group.